# Why does variable inspection seem to correct my sorting?

Tags: php, sorting

### In a Nutshell

Why would a function that returns an incorrect array ordering return the expected ordering when I call `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on the array just before sorting?

### The Nitty Gritties

I'm trying to print basic info about the next few events collected from several Google calendars, sorted by a custom `uasort()` based on the event start date/time.

```
function getUpcomingEvents() 
{
    $calUrls = array( /* Four Google calendar URLs */);

    foreach ($calUrls as $url)
    {
        $calEvents = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

        for($i=0; $i<count($calEvents['items']); $i++)
        {
            $item = $calEvents['items'][$i];

            $events[] = array(
                'title' => $item['summary'],
                'description' => $item['description'],
                'start' => date_create($item['start']['dateTime']),
                'end' =>  date_create($item['end']['dateTime']),
                'htmlLink' => $item['htmlLink']
            );
        }
    }   

    //print_r($events);  // <-- **LOOK AT ME**

    uasort($events, function($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a['start']->date) - strtotime($b['start']->date);
    });

    return $events;
} 

...*snip*...

<?php foreach(getUpcomingEvents() as $event) : ?>
    <li><h3><?php echo date_format($event['start'], 'M j'); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I load the page with print_r() commented out this way, my list items print out in this order:

`Feb 19, Feb 21, Feb 23, Feb 26, Mar 5, Feb 19, Feb 16,...`
(Note: these represent events from calendars 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,..., respectively, so it doesn't simply reflect the order of the calendar requests.)

After uncommenting the `print_r()` (with no other changes), the list items print ordered chronologically:

`Feb 10, Feb 14, Feb 16, Feb 16, Feb 16, Feb 19, Feb 19,...`
(Note: these are the printed `<li>'s`, not the output of `print_r()` itself, which is not sorted).

**I Have Tried:**
* declaring `global $events;` above `getUpcomingEvents()` in case it was a variable scoping issue
* using `usort` instead of `uasort`, and a separated comparison function declaration instead of an anonymous one
* building up `$events` as an explicitly indexed array (`$events[$i] = ...`) instead of using the `[]` operator in case that would help maintain a more stable array order
* assigning `getUpcomingEvents()` to a new variable before passing it into the `foreach`

Is variable inspection really affecting my sorting or have I gone wrong somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

No, print_r does not affect your array. It just shows you the information of the variable.

From [PHP page](http://php.net/print_r)

```
print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable
```

Comment: Thanks, I have referenced the PHP documentation, but the documentation doesn't necessarily preclude the possibility of modification as a side-effect, does it?  I should emphasize I don't think it _probable_ that my variable is being modified, but it sure seems like it based on the behavior I described. I've updated the question title to better focus on the problem.